# renderAs PDF for specific block

Tags: apex, pdf, renderas

I'm using code to save page As PDF, with custom save button. but what If I need more than one save button in the same page and each button will save part of the page?? How can I handle that issue ?

**Save as PDF link**

```
<apex:commandLink target="_blank" 
                  action="{! saveToPdf }" 
                  value="Save as PDF">
      <apex:param assignTo="{! renderedFileName }" 
                  value="leads-List.pdf"/>
</apex:commandLink>
```

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="lead" 
           showHeader="false" 
           id="partnersPage" 
           renderAs="{!renderingService}" 
           recordSetVar="myrecords" 
           extensions="customCtrl,SaveAsPdfExtension"
           applyBodyTag="false">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <head>
      <style>
          @page {
                size: A4;
                margin: 25mm;
                @bottom-center {
                    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
                }
            }
      </style>
  </head>

  <body>

      <apex:outputPanel id="mainpanel"> 
      <apex:form id="mainform" >
          <apex:pageBlock title="Partners List">

              <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" >
                   <apex:commandButton immediate="true" 
                                       value="Back to Dashboard" 
                                       action="/apex/dashboard"/>
                   <apex:commandLink target="_blank" 
                                     action="{! saveToPdf }" 
                                     value="Save as PDF">
                       <apex:param assignTo="{! renderedFileName }" 
                                   value="leads-List.pdf"/>
                   </apex:commandLink>
              </apex:pageBlockSection>

              <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myrecords}" var="pt" id="mid">   

                  <apex:column value="{!pt.Name}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!pt.Phone__c}"/>
                  <apex:column value="{!pt.Company__c}"/>

              </apex:pageBlockTable>
              <apex:pagemessages id="msg" />     
          </apex:pageBlock>


             <apex:pageBlock id="another_list" 
                             rendered="{!anotherListFlg}" 
                             title="another list">
                   <apex:commandLink target="_blank" 
                                     action="{! saveToPdf }" 
                                     value="Save as PDF">
                       <apex:param assignTo="{! renderedFileName }" 
                                   value="another-List.pdf"/>
                   </apex:commandLink>
                  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!anotherList}" var="agr">
                  <apex:column headerValue="Name" value="{!agr.name}"/>
                  <apex:column headerValue="Phone" value="{!agr.Phone__c}"/>


               </apex:pageBlockTable>
               <apex:pagemessages id="msg2" />

          </apex:pageBlock>


      </apex:form>
    </apex:outputPanel>
  </body>
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

**SaveAsPdfExtension Apex Class**

```
public class SaveAsPdfExtension {

    public SaveAsPdfExtension(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    }

    // Determines what kind of rendering to use for the page request
    public String renderingService { get; private set; }

    // Allow the page to set the PDF file name
    public String renderedFileName { 
        get; 
        set { renderedFileName = this.sanitizeFileName(value); }
    }

    // Rendered content MIME type, used to affect HTTP response
    public String renderedContentType {
        get {
            String renderedContentType = 'text/html'; // the default

            if( ! this.renderingAsHtml() ) {
                // Provides a MIME type for a PDF document 
                renderedContentType = 'application/pdf';

                // Add a file name for the PDF file
                if( this.renderedFileName != null) {
                    // This is supposed to set the file name, but it doesn't work
                    renderedContentType += '#' + this.renderedFileName;

                    // This is a work-around to set the file name
                    ApexPages.currentPage().getHeaders().put(
                        'content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + 
                         this.renderedFileName);
                }
            }

            return renderedContentType;
        }
    }

    // Are we rendering to HTML or PDF?
    public Boolean renderingAsHtml() {
        return ( (renderingService == null) || 
                 ( ! renderingService.startsWith('PDF')) );
    }

    // Action method to save (or "print") to PDF
    public PageReference saveToPdf() {
        renderingService = 'PDF';
        return null;
    }

    // Private helper -- basic, conservative santization
    private String sanitizeFileName(String unsafeName) {
        String allowedCharacters = '0-9a-zA-Z-_.';
        String sanitizedName = 
            unsafeName.replaceAll('[^' + allowedCharacters + ']', '');
        // You might also want to check filename length, 
        // that the filename ends in '.pdf', etc.
        return(sanitizedName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating different VF's pages and then combining all of them on one page.

Answer (score 1):

I think use of render attribute & set it to false on save button click on blocks that you don't want in pdf & viceversa.

I hope this idea will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use visualforce components- write you individual blocks you want to save as pdf in a separate components and use all those components in single VF page. here you can print whole page or particular block you need.